# How to find the total disk writes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm trying to find the total number of disk writes in MySQL. I used the following command in the MySQL terminal.

```
>SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
```

I got a list of different attributes status and few which made sense where :

```
Innodb_data_writes

Innodb_data_written

Innodb_dblwr_writes
```

So, which one represents the total disk writes in MySQL?

Comment: What would "total disk writes" be? MB/sec, IOPS used, frequency of writing?

Comment: Sometimes InnoDB writes multiple blocks in one request; do you want N or 1 for that?  Consider, for example,  `Innodb_dblwr_pages`_written versus `Innodb_dblwr_writes`.  I've systems where the ratio is over 80 pages per write.

Comment: Some OS tool, like iostat / vmstat, may be a better approach.